# In G Suite, how do do you block an entire domain of senders?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have a blocked senders list set up for gmail in my G Suite domain.  Included in that list are entire domains.  However, I still receive messages that have have email addresses with that domain in the from field.  Is there something special that needs to be done to block all senders from a domain?

I am asking as a G Suite Administrator.  I want to block a domain from sending emails to my domain using the G Suite Administration app.  I am blocking the senders by going to Apps > G Suite > Gmail > Advanced Settings > Blocked senders.

Comment: Are you asking as a G Suite administrator or as Gmail user?

Comment: I am asking as a G Suite admin.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make that clear. i.e. mention that you are using the G Suite administration app and what sections you used to block the senders.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login as Admin to the G Suite admin console. Go to Apps -> G Suite -
   Gmail -> Advanced Settings.
2. Scroll down to "Blocked Senders" and click on "edit" to the right.
3. Here you will create a name for the blocking rule, a blocked address/domain list, and a message to send back to blocked senders.
4. Press save to save your changes. They go into effect immediately.

Comment: This is the method I have been using.  It does not work.

Comment: [According to the docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2364632?hl=en) it won't work.